# Determine Accuracy of Independent Probabilities

Tags: bernoulli-numbers, confidence-interval

Below are my calculated probabilities (using naive bayes), and whether or not the event actually occurred. How do i determine the margin of error for these probabilities?

```
P(s)    s
---------
0.329   0
0.786   1
0.591   1
0.641   1
0.84    0
0.402   1
0.505   0
0.314   1
0.493   0
0.534   0
0.551   0
0.661   1
0.332   0
0.554   0
0.433   1
0.364   1
0.462   1
0.36    1
0.25    0
0.454   0
0.524   1
0.518   1
0.57    0
0.46    0
0.641   0
0.336   0
0.484   1
0.521   1
0.413   0
0.728   1
```

Comment: Calculated probabilities for what?  Bayes using what model?  Without context, I think these data are essentially useless.

Comment: The bayes was just an aside. Essentially, I want to see how accurate my bayes model is at spitting out the probability of an event occuring. Above are the probabilities it produced, along with whether or not the event actually occurred.

Comment: @RobertIsrael actually, this might not be useless. This is a set of numbers that occured each time a situation was repeated.

Comment: So...your prior probability was $.329$, the event did not occur (at least that's what I guess the $0$ means) and that caused you to revise your guess to $.786$?  How does that work?

Comment: @lulu these are all independent probabilities assigned to independent events. Think of it as given a certain persons health decisions they had a .329 probability of getting the flu one year (followed by a 0 indicating they did not get the flu). The 2nd person had a .786 probability of getting the flu (followed by a 1 meaning they did get the flu). This process is repeated 30 times for 30 independent individuals. With the data collected, I am now trying to see if the probabilities assigned were at all accurate, probably through a confidence interval.

Comment: You only get one observation per event?  Clearly there isn't enough information to assess the accuracy of any given prediction.  Are you trying to decide whether your overall process of assigning probabilities has any validity?  What I generally do in such cases is to imagine that you are betting $1$ per observation, with a payout determined by the probabilities.  Thus if you say $p=.25$ then my dollar returns $3$ if the event happens.  If your numbers are good, that game has expectation $0$.  If you get a lot of trials then you can measure the actual return on the game.

Comment: To stress:  Absent context, it's hard to say what sort of "confidence interval" applies here.  You might try asking if a $5\%$ change in the probabilities makes my game fair, or something like that.

Comment: Also worth noting: in practice,  this "game theoretic" approach works best if the probabilities are all mid range (fairly near $.5$).  If your problem is prone to outliers, then you might get a huge payout on a $p=.001$ event, and this will badly skew your analysis.  So the overall context matters enormously.

Comment: Note:  I just ran my game using your numbers.  Not bad!  You win about $91$ cents with thirty bets....so quite accurate.

Comment: Draw a [receiver operating characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) curve, which may suggest your estimated probabilities have a minimal relationship with the actual outcomes.  For example of those events where you think the probability is over $\frac12$, $8$ occurred and $7$ did not, with something similar for those with probability under $\frac12$.

Comment: To go one step further:  if I add $.01688$ to each of your probabilities I get a fair game.  Very small correction.  Given the extremely small sample, I wouldn't reject the hypothesis that your estimates were accurate.

Comment: @lulu: I wouldn't reject the hypothesis the estimates bear no relationship to the actual outcomes: of the top ten estimates, five did not happen; of the bottom ten estimates, five did happen.